# With bazel why do I keep fetching wrong build artifacts from the remote cache despite using --define or --action_env?

Tags: caching, bazel, bazel-remote-cache

From what I read (documentation seems to be quite sparse) you can use the `--define` and `--action_env` arguments to let Bazel build artifacts with a different 'configuration' and thus (as I would expect) not taking artifacts from a configured remote cache.

Is this correct?

I'd expect this command to take artifacts from cache if executed with identical values:

```
bazel build \
    --remote_cache=<remote-cache-details> \
    --define FOO=foo \
    --action_env BAR=bar \
    <target>
```

And I'd expect a re-build to be forced if one of the variables/values provided with `--define` or `--action_env` changed.

Is that still correct?

I'm currently facing the following situation: I somehow managed to 'poison' the remote cache with artifacts built against an incompatible version of some a library (glibc in my case), and now I'm getting errors when building with a configured remote cache:

```
...
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/bzlws/generators/cpp/cpp: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/bzlws/generators/cpp/cpp)
```

And I don't get this error when building without remote cache or building on a system with matching version of GLIBC, this is why I suspect this to be a caching issue.

I know there are better ways to provide Bazel with details about the toolchain, but my question is about how Bazel decides what to look for in the cache and how that can be influenced.

I'm creating an execution log file with `--execution_log_json_file` which shows the variables I provide using `--action_env` actually show up, so these *should* be taken into account.

Also changing values provided with `--action_env` result in longer builds.

Yet I keep getting this linker error when using the cache.

Is it possible that `--action_env` *does* retrigger a build but when it comes to linking Bazel takes libraries from the cache (e.g. `glibc`) despite it didn't build, i.e. taken from another machine, so changing the build environment doesn't affect this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[--remote_instance_name](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--remote_instance_name) is passed to the remote cache, and most implementations will use that to separate the cache keys. The REST API includes it in the URL, the gRPC API includes it in the request body.

For example, [bazel-remote](https://github.com/buchgr/bazel-remote) says this:

> If the `--enable_ac_key_instance_mangling` flag is specified and the instance name is not empty, then action cache keys are hashed along with the instance name to produce the action cache lookup key.

`--action_env` and `--define` only affect some actions, if you're fetching source files or some other action those don't affect then the cache key stays the same.