# How to make Bazel correctly cache dependencies built by itself?

Tags: bazel, bazel-remote-cache

I have a (relatively small) Bazel rule for some `configure`/`make` based project, say `xmlsec1` - you can take any other, the important thing seems to be the external tooling behind `foreign_cc`:

`xmlsec1.BUILD`:

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "configure_make")

filegroup(name="all_srcs", srcs=glob(["**"]))

configure_make(
    name="xmlsec1",
    lib_name="xmlsec1",
    lib_source=":all_srcs",
    configure_command="configure",
    configure_in_place=True,
    out_binaries=["xmlsec1"],
    targets=["install"],
)
```

`xmlsec1.bzl`:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

def xmlsec1():
    http_archive(
        name = "xmlsec1",
        url = "https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/download/xmlsec1-1.2.37.tar.gz",
        sha256 = "5f8dfbcb6d1e56bddd0b5ec2e00a3d0ca5342a9f57c24dffde5c796b2be2871c",
        build_file = "@//:xmlsec1.BUILD",
    )
```

All works fine for me until Bazel's remote cache gets activated and I'm building among different Linux distributions.

To avoid cache collisions I'm running `bazel build` with `--action_env=SYSTEM_DIGEST="$(cat /etc/os-release)"`, resulting in different hashes on different distros.

While this approach seems to work for the artifacts defined in `xmlsec1` (I can see this from the execution logs and observing expected re-builds), the `foreign_cc` part seems to built without those `action_env` variables.

This is what I get when I try to build `@xmlsec1//:xmlsec1` (line breaks for readability):

```
 + /home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/8f6a55c898f3ec22f87d9cee5890b9e5/sandbox/processwrapper-sandbox/5/execroot/my_project_packages/bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/rules_foreign_cc/toolchains\
/make/bin/make install
/home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/8f6a55c898f3ec22f87d9cee5890b9e5/sandbox/processwrapper-sandbox/5/execroot/my_project_packages/bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/rules_foreign_cc/toolchains\
/make/bin/make: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/8f6a55c898f3ec22f87d9cee5890b9e5/sandbox/processwrapper-sandbox/5/execroot/my_project_packages/bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/rules_foreign_cc/toolchains/make/bin/make)
/home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/8f6a55c898f3ec22f87d9cee5890b9e5/sandbox/processwrapper-sandbox/5/execroot/my_project_packages/bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/rules_foreign_cc/toolchains\
/make/bin/make: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/8f6a55c898f3ec22f87d9cee5890b9e5/sandbox/processwrapper-sandbox/5/execroot/my_project_packages/bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/rules_foreign_cc/toolchains/make/bin/make)
```

I get this linker error only with bazel remote cache being activated and (this is the interesting part) having `xmlsec1` built on a recent distribution (say Ubuntu 22.04) and then trying to build it on Centos-8.

So I guess this is what's going on:

- `make` from `foreign_cc` get's built and linked against a recent version of `GLIBC`, ignoring values provided with `--action_env`
- `foreign_cc` artifacts are being stored in the bazel remote cache
- another build on an older distro (Centos-8) also tries to build `make` and has no reason not to take the artifacts from the cache, since `--action_env` values are also ignored here, resulting in the same hash
- since the binaries are linked against a version of `GLIBC` which is not available yet on Centos-8 they are not compatible and crash with the error you see above.

So my question(s) is(/are):

- Is that intended behavior? why is `--action_env` being ignored for builds Bazel runs implicitly (and not for those defined explicitly)?
- Is there a way to apply those rules for Bazels own dependencies?
- Is there a better way to define system properties with effects on all Builds?

Comment: make is built in the exec configuration - have you tried setting the same action_env using `--host_action_env` as well?

Comment: One of my many attempts to work around this was to fiddle with `--host_action_env`, using the same values as with `--action_env` but with no effect. I'll give it another try, though, since now it seems like I have a reliable way to reproduce this problem. (empty cache => rebuild in different orders)

Comment: Have you tried my answer to your other question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75140088/2263152? I think using that to separate cached artifacts between operating systems will work more robustly.

Comment: I'll do that as soon as I'm encountering the issue again - might need to flush the cache first..